# A different flavor of Const Reference?

Tags: c++, syntax

what's the difference between `std::vector<T> const &` and `const std::vector<T> &` ?

I'm used to `const T &`, but this "`T const &`" is different to me.

and forgive me for my ignorance.

Comment: There is no difference, I like to use the 1st form, some people like the 2nd.  This is also correct `const std::vector<T> const &` and the same as above.

Comment: @RichardCritten: No, that's a syntax error: `duplicate 'const'`

Comment: @Richard Critten: Applying the same qualifier twice directly (as in your example) is not allowed in C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are completely equal.

You can verify this by trying to compile the following code and see how the compiler complains about a redefinition:

```
#include <vector>

void f(std::vector<int> const &) {}
void f(const std::vector<int> &) {} // error: redefinition
```